# Apache Camel scripting problem

Tags: java, javascript, apache, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I have a very strange problem with Apache ActiveMQ with Camel - I tried the examples with javascript and groovy, but they both produce error "Failed to install route: Failed to create route... because of No language could be found for: groovy"

The groovy example I use is

```
<route>
    <from uri="queue:foo"/>
    <filter>
        <groovy>request.lineItems.any { i -> i.value > 100 }</groovy>
        <to uri="queue:bar"/>
    </filter>
</route>
```

The same issue goes for JavaScript. The only scripting that works is "Simple" - the internal Camel scripting language. Please give me advice how to fix this. I am using ActiveMQ 5.2.4 with the integrated Apache Camel 2.4.0.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Yeah you need to add the JARs from camel-script and the scripting language of choice, eg for groovy you need the groovy JAR. If you run AMQ you should drop them in the lib folder.

Answer (score 8):

Do you have a dependency on camel-script fulfilled?

For instance in maven this would be declared as:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
    <artifactId>camel-script</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.0</version>
</dependency>
```

In your `<dependencies>` declaration.

Comment: I use Camel as part of ActiveMQ and not inside my project itself. So where should I find the pom.xml file?

Answer (score 0):

I added artifact camel-groovy because camel-script didn't work for me.

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
        <artifactId>camel-groovy</artifactId>
        <version>2.23.0</version>
</dependency>
```